# Retraining Keras Model Several Times Leads to Out of Memory Error

Tags: python, memory, keras

So I have a setup where I have some data and train a Keras model on it. Once I do that, I add some more data and train the model again. This process continues several times. Eventually though, my computer says it has run out of CPU RAM. I have a suspicion that the Keras model is building a new graph every time. How do I check this? Below is my resetting method.

```
def reset(self):
    session = K.get_session()
    for layer in self.model.layers: 
        if hasattr(layer, 'kernel_initializer'):
            layer.kernel.initializer.run(session=session)
        if hasattr(layer, 'bias_initializer') and layer.bias is not None:
            layer.bias.initializer.run(session=session)
```

Any help or tips on debugging memory issues would be greatly appreciated. I'm using Keras 2.1.6

Comment: All you need to train a keras model is:  `model.fit(X, Y, batch_size = ..., epochs = ...)`.  What is "add more data"?

Comment: The idea is that after adding more data I want to reset and train from scratch. In other words, every time I want to 'fit' my X and Y are different

Comment: I see... but what is "add more data" in your code? What are you doing to "add more data"? Are you saving the old models or something like that?